# Can I put a page view controller within a table view cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uipageviewcontroller

I'm wondering if I could put a page view within a table view cell. Basically I'm trying to get each table view cell to be able to scroll left/right for more content.

Can I do it by putting a page view within a table view cell? Or is there another way to be able to swipe left/right in a table view cell?

Comment: @rmaddy Yeah I know I could use a page control (not actually put a whole view controller into the thing), but I'm wondering if it's practical.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to load another view controller and add its view as a subview of another controller's view.

Although it's not recommended by Apple's guidelines:

> Each custom view controller object you create is responsible for
>   managing all of the views in a single view hierarchy. [...] The
>   one-to-one correspondence between a view controller and the views in
>   its view hierarchy is the key design consideration. You should not use
>   multiple custom view controllers to manage different portions of the
>   same view hierarchy.

More info on the guidelines click [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/AboutViewControllers/AboutViewControllers.html)

A better way to do it is using a UIScrollView and a UIPageControl like this…

**cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
     cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }    

    NSArray *photo = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"image3.png"], nil];
    self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 150)];
    self.scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.scrollView.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleBlack; //Scroll bar style
    self.scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    [self.scrollView setDelegate:self];
    //Show horizontal scroll bar

    self.scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES; //Close vertical scroll bar
    self.scrollView.bounces = YES; //Cancel rebound effect
    self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES; //Flat screen
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(640, 30);

    NSLog(@"LOG");

    self.pageControl = [[UIPageControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 155, 320, 40)];
    self.pageControl.numberOfPages = photo.count;
    self.pageControl.currentPage = 0;
    self.pageControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.pageControl setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:self.pageControl];


    for(int i = 0; i < photo.count; i++)
    {
        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x = (self.scrollView.frame.size.width *i) + 10;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        frame.size = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width - 20, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);

        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        [imageView setImage:[photo objectAtIndex:i]];


        [self.scrollView addSubview:imageView];
        self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width*photo.count, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
    }

    [cell.contentView addSubview:self.scrollView];


    return cell;
}
```

**update `PageControl`**

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGFloat pageWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width;

    //int page = floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth*0.3) / pageWidth) + 1);

    self.pageControl.currentPage = (int)scrollView.contentOffset.x / (int)pageWidth;
    NSLog(@"CURRENT PAGE %d", self.pageControl.currentPage);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can.

However, be aware that you can't get rid of the black background to the page control in it if you choose to go that route. I did this a couple days ago but ended up getting rid of the page view controller in favor of using a `UIScrollView` that has paging enabled and a `UIPageControl`. I use the `-scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:` scroll view delegate method to determine when to determine the `currentPage` in the page control.

If you're going to have quite a few views in the scroll view, it would be more memory efficient to use a collection view instead of a normal scroll view.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a UIPageview, try to put another UITableview (rotated by 90 degrees in anticlockwise direction)inside a cell. This will give you more control over touch events and more customization too.

1) Have a class for UITableViewCell and an xib file too, say PageViewTableCell

2) Xib file should have a UITableView inside the cell

3) Rotate the table when awakeFromNib is called

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
  {
      horizontalTable.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI_2);
      horizontalTable.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,horizontalTable.frame.size.width,horizontalTable.frame.size.height);
  }
```

4) Have the delegate and datasource for horizontalTable according to your design.

5) Load the main table which has the above customized cell

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self.mainTable registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"PageViewTableCell"
                                          bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]
    forCellReuseIdentifier:@"samplecell"];

}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    PageViewTableCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"samplecell"];
    return cell;
}
```